# List line break/spacing format issue

Tags: support, editor, markdown-rendering

In the following list, what is the proper way to insert a line break before the final element where indicated (courtesy mspaint)?

[screenshot http://i.snag.gy/D7EsT.jpg](http://i.snag.gy/D7EsT.jpg)

I expected the above to have the line break there, but there was no break. I kludged it by writing `<br/><br/>` at the end of the last item in the nested list but I couldn't figure out the "correct" way to do it.

---

Edit: Regarding some answers below. This is the general format I want, and am wondering how to do it without an explicit `<br/><br/>`:

- Item with space below.
- Item with space below.

  - Group of items with no spaces.
  - Group of items with no spaces.
  - Group of items with no spaces. Last item, should have space below.
- Last item in list.

Without `<br><br>` after the last item in the inner group, the last item in the toplevel list does not have a space above it. It looks like, based on the answers so far though, that there isn't really a "proper" way to do this, but the workarounds are easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't really a proper way. Our markdown engine will try to merge adjacent lists and that's that. You've found one way around it.

There are others, like using a HTML comment (`<!-- -->`) to break up adjacent blocks of formatting that would otherwise be merged:

> - Here's a list
>
>   - with a sublist
>
> - and a HTML comment above this bullet point to keep this from merging with the list above

```
* Here's a list

 * with a sublist

<!-- -->

* and a HTML comment above this bullet point to keep this from merging with the list above
```

HTML comments can also be used to break apart adjacent quote boxes or blocks of code.

Comment: Note for future readers: this only visually works for bulleted lists. For a numbered list, the count would reset after the break.

Comment: Huh, that's an interesting approach. It still seems like a kludge, but I will start doing that. I like how it doesn't involve adding markup to the last item of the sublist. @animuson Ah good point thanks.

Comment: It appears `<br/><br/>` is a better choice to reliably break up lists as you wish to. It **will keep** the numbering correctly too, in numbered lists.