# Stack Exchange Markdown rendering shows incorrect list spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, list

*Related to, but believed not a duplicate of, [List line break/spacing format issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204631/list-line-break-spacing-format-issue).*

---

Below is explained a rendering issue for MarkDown affecting many if not all SE sites.

Further, I seem to be finding additional issues related to rendering or parsing of MarkDown in SE as to deviate markedly and adversely from generic handling of MarkDown text.

What information can be provided, for now only about the issue described below, specifically regarding the following questions?:

- Is an official channel available to communicate such issues to SE staff responsible for development, marketing, or quality-assurance?
- Has any such channel been invoked for the issue?
- Has a response been offered that either acknowledges the issue or rejects the complaint?

---

Currently, Stack Exchange sites appear to format incorrectly the below Markdown content:

```
- List item.

  * Sublist item

  * Sublist item

  *Should be space above this line*.

- List item.
```

The spacing between all items should be roughly uniform. In fact, the spacing immediately above the inner list is inappropriately expansive, whereas that immediately after it is inappropriately condensed.

*As currently rendered by Stack Exchange*:
**(Note: Since these comments originally appeared, [system changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446) have been introduced, intending to mitigate the problems described. These improvements may be reflected in the formatting of text below.)**

- List item.

  - Sublist item
  - Sublist item

  *Should be space above this line*.
- List item.

Comment: The mobile site renders it correctly.

Comment: @Sonic On the mobile site I see adequate space above the italicized line but inadequate space below, compared to the reverse on the desktop. (The Android app does render correctly!)

Comment: I briefly looked over this and while I don't have a fix at hand right now, I just wanted to point out that this is not an issue with our Markdown rendering but with CSS rules kicking in. The generated markup is sane. However, we have a CSS rule in place that's explicitly changing spacing to come up with this result. Ad hoc, I can't tell why that rule is in place so we'll need to do some digging.

Comment: @HamVocke: Thanks for the information. I had noticed a variety of quirks from time to time, though I only mentioned the most noticeable one. Would you be able to address perhaps the more fundamental question of how users might seek resolutions to issues of this kind via official channels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been completed as part of new [post formatting changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting).

Comment: The new formatting has a superior appearance compared to the previous, but spacing between regular paragraphs is quite substantial, and is greater than spacing between items and paragraphs within lists. The changes described are complicated, leaving me unable to make a formal evaluation of the technique. Nevertheless, I notice that a browser will by default provide spacing of list items and paragraphs that is even and natural, and balanced with spacing between regular paragraphs. This observation makes me wonder whether an approach worth considering for SE is simplification down to the basics.

Comment: @epl Thank you for the feedback. I'll pass it along to our Stacks team. Feel free to add to the [new post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353446/new-post-formatting) post as well - lots of great discussion happening there too

Answer (score 4):

It's been like that since forever. :-(

Either shrug and live with it, or avoid authoring complicated lists -- either one level of list with optional list paragraphs, or two levels of lists but without list paragraphs.

---

You can insert a extra vertical  line using `&nbsp;<br>` or something like that ...

- List item.

  - Sublist item
  - Sublist item

  *Should be space above this line*.
- List item.

... but you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you. I am now trying to direct the focus of the question to how the issue might be resolved satisfactorily by SE.